# search address on google map api

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-maps, geocoding

i rewrite the message for better understandnig

how can i search for address only using google map api.

if i will search for adderss i dont want google give a bussiness with the same name of the address ( i don't want to get bussiness at all)

thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of searches are you doing? What kind of results do you want?

Comment: @chris , i want to search only for address , i dont want to get bussines.
for example :
if i will search for tel aviv,galina google will give me place(bussines ) called galina , and i dont want to get galina i want to search only for address.

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with using the Geocoder?

Comment: when i use Geocoder i can search for country,city,address but i don't get the address ,for example israel,tel aviv,dimona i won't get dimona address on the map.
and if i use google maps i can get dimona address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the AJAX Search API, there is an [argument](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_fonje_local) for Local Search which allows you to exclude business listings:

> mrt? - This optional argument
>   specifies which type of listing the
>   user is interested in. Valid values
>   include:
>
> - blended - request KML, Local Business Listings, and Geocode results
> - kmlonly - request KML and Geocode results
> - localonly - request Local Business Listings and Geocode results

Answer (score 1):

Would the [GoogleBar](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#LocalSearch) work for you?  It won't return business results unless they're searched for.  Here's an [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/control-googlebar.html).

**UPDATE:**
If you ONLY want to search for addresses - the Geocoder is really your only option.

Comment: @ chris even if they will search for business i don't want to show on the map

Comment: @chris when i use Geocoder i can search for country,city,address but i don't get th address 
for example
israel,tel aviv,dimona i won't get dimona 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_geocoding_extraction


and if i use google maps i can get dimona 
http://maps.google.com/?hl=iw&ie=UTF8&ll=32.226743,34.747009&spn=2.183969,2.69989&z=9

Comment: Entering "Dimona, Israel" into this Google geocoder tester worked just fine. http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/googlegeocode/test.cfm (returned lat/long of 34.9484000,31.0950000). Same thing for "Tel Aviv, Israel" - 34.7595000,32.0554000.

Comment: dimona in israel is a city and also street name . you got the city in your search.
sorry that i confuse you but you can try 
israel,tel aviv,balfour 
balfour is only a street.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take the latitude and longitude returned by the geocoder and display it as a marker on the map yourself. The geocoder API won't automatically generate a map for you.

Comment: thenk for quick response
but its not what i ment.
i want to search for address using the google api.
but not throw the geocoding because its not giving good results

Comment: I have a lot of experience with the google maps api, could you post your code?

Comment: @avnic Without some example addresses and knowing what you're hoping to get back from the geocoder, we can't help you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder appears to be working fine here. I am able to get correct latitude/longitude results for the following queries:

- Dimona
- Dimona, Israel
- Tel Aviv
- Tel Aviv, Israel
- Israel